# event handler calling wrapped async functions in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, meteor, event-handling

With

```
var twitPost = Meteor._wrapAsync(twit.post.bind(twit));

function process(screen_name)
{
  twitGet('users/show', {'screen_name': screen_name});
}
```

a synchronous call to process("screen_name") works fine, but

```
  stream.on('tweet', function(tweet)
  {
    process(tweet.user.screen_name);
  });
```

yields `Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.`

Any ideas how/if I could make this work? I would like to go via some processing function that can do other stuff except call twitPost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is written, methods that use Meteor code (particularly ones that access Collections) need to be wrapped with a Fiber. One way to do so is to use `Meteor.bindEnvironment`:

```
stream.on('tweet', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(tweet) {
  process(tweet.user.screen_name);
}));
```